# New lines and/or carriage returns not getting converted

Tags: powershell

Re-edited my question to try and make it more clear - version 2 :-)

I have the following code in a disk module within a function which uses the Get-WmiObject which pushes the data into a $LogMsg string which intern is then used in a LogToEmail function which is in another module (LogToEmail "Drive space is low" $LogMsg;)

```
    if ($AlertPercent -gt 0)
    {
        $filter = "DeviceID='" + $DriveLetter + "'";
        $body = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $ServerName -Filter $filter |
                        Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3 -and ((($_.FreeSpace/$_.Size*100) -as [float]) -lt $AlertPercent)} |
                        Sort-Object -Property Name | 
                        Select-Object @{"Label"="Server";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.SystemName)}},
                                                        Name,
                                                        VolumeName,
                                                        FileSystem,
                                                        Description,
                                                        VolumeDirty,
                                                  @{"Label"="DiskSize(GB)";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.Size/1GB) -as [float]}},
                                                  @{"Label"="FreeSpace(GB)";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1GB) -as [float]}},
                                                  @{"Label"="%Free";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/$_.Size*100) -as [float]}} |
                            Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String);
    }
    else
    {
        $filter = "DeviceID='" + $DriveLetter + "'";
        $body = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $ServerName -Filter $filter |
                        Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3} |
                        Sort-Object -Property Name | 
                        Select-Object @{"Label"="Server";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.SystemName)}},
                                                        Name,
                                                        VolumeName,
                                                        FileSystem,
                                                        Description,
                                                        VolumeDirty,
                                                  @{"Label"="DiskSize(GB)";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.Size/1GB) -as [float]}},
                                                  @{"Label"="FreeSpace(GB)";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1GB) -as [float]}},
                                                  @{"Label"="%Free";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/$_.Size*100) -as [float]}} |
                            Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String);
    }

    if ($body.Length -gt 0)
    {
      #Set the log message
        $LogMsg = "The following drive '" + $pDriveLetter + "', on server '" + $ServerName + "', is low on space.`n" + $body.Trim();

        #Log the stopped service(s) to the log file
        LogToFile $LogMsg;

        #Log the stopped service(s) to the host screen
        LogToHost $LogMsg;

        #Log the stopped service(s) to the email receipient
        LogToEmail "Drive space is low" $LogMsg;
    }

    #Set log information message 
    $LogInfoMsg = "Ended checking drive space on server:" + $ServerName;

    #Log the date and time started checking searched service(s) on the server
    LogToFile $LogInfoMsg

    #Log the date and time started checking searched service(s) on the server
    LogToHost $LogInfoMsg
}
catch
{
    #write out the error into a string format
    $LogMsg = "- ERROR: " + ($_.Exception.ErrorRecord | Out-String);

    #Log the error message to the log file
    LogToFile $LogMsg;

    #Log the error message to the host screen
    LogToHost $LogMsg;

    #Log, the error message to the email recipient
    LogToEmail ("PowerShell error on " + (split-path $MyInvocation.PSCommandPath -leaf)) $LogMsg;
}
```

The $LogMsg is then passed to the log module as

```
$Message = New-MimeMessage $global:EmailFrom $global:EmailTo $Subject $LogMsg $global:EmailCC
```

and then to the email module as $Body as a string parameter in the New-MimeMessage function which is supposed to convert it to HTML via ConvertTo-HTML functionality.

```
    $BodyAsHtml = $global:BodyAsHTML
    if ($BodyAsHtml)
    {
        $TextPart = New-Object MimeKit.TextPart("html")
        #$RetConstructedMessage = $true
    }
    else
    {
      $TextPart = New-Object MimeKit.TextPart("plain")
    }

    $Header = "
              <style>
              DIV {font-family:'courier', monospace}
              </style>
              "
    $BodyHTML = ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header -Body $Body | Out-String
    $TextPart.Text = $BodyHTML
```

However, the ConvertTo-Html is not encoding the new line/carriage returns even though the debugger in Visual Studio Code seems to show correctly but via the browser on GMail or on Microsoft Outlook after the email has been sent, it shows as a continuous one-liner.  I don't do any HTML coding to force line breaks where I want them as the Get-WmiObject should have them in as plain text places the new lines and/or carriage returns.  I have included images to try and help what I am seeing.

Mousing over $BodyHTML string variable in Visual Studio Code debugger
[image: Mousing over $BodyHTML string variable in Visual Studio Code debugger]

The email view on the browser on GMail
[image: The email view on the browser on GMail]

The email view on the browser on Microsoft Outlook
[image: The email view on the browser on Microsoft Outlook]

Comment: Line breaks are lost in HTML, unless there are `<br>` or `<pre>` tags?

Comment: Thank you for responding @vonPryz.  I re-edited my question.  Hopefully, it makes more sense.

Comment: Remove the `|  Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String` when you create `$body`. This will return a table-style string as formatted for the console screen only. `ConvertTo-Html` cannot make a HTML style table from that. If you need the Format-Table display in your log, then create a variable for that especially for logging, but leave the `$body` object array in tact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you need to remove the `| Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String` when you create the `$body` variable.
This will return a table-style string as **formatted for the console screen only**.
You can check with `$body.GetType().FullName`, which because of the `| Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String` will return `System.String`

If you leave that out, `$body.GetType().FullName` shows it is a `System.Object[]`

This is what you need for the `ConvertTo-Html` so it can create a HTML-style table from that data.

If you need the Format-Table in the log, use a new variable to get the table format you want in there, or have this long line:

```
$LogMsg = "The following drive '$pDriveLetter', on server '$ServerName', is low on space.`r`n{0}" -f ($body | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String).Trim()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Theo.  I was trying all different things but the wrong ones.  I just have to move things around a little but works like a charm... :-)